# Density plots from matlab to matplotlib

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot, density-plot

Since some years ago I use matlab for my plots (mostly density plots), but now I want to change to matplotlib. I have a problem trying to figure out how to get analogous plots in matplotlib. I have to represent a 2D array. In matlab I used to use the surf function, and then change to view(2) (az=0 and el=90). An example:

```
surf(X,Y,log10(z),'FaceColor','interp','EdgeColor','none')
view(2)
```

In matplotlib I have tried some functions, but I have not got the same feeling. m3plot is a computationally expensive toolkit and it is not the same as using surf. imshow does not allow to use log functions in his arguments (like the example), and log values is something mandatory for me. Then it is pcolor, but I can not find a 'FaceColor'-like option to smooth the edges. I would like to know if someone knows what is the best equivalent in matplotlib.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: You are wrong about `imshow`, `imshow(log(z))` will work just fine.  You can also have the color mapper do the log-mapping for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455044/problems-with-zeros-in-matplotlib-colors-lognorm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546475/how-can-i-draw-a-log-normalized-imshow-plot-with-a-colorbar-representing-the-raw

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [mayavi](http://mayavi.sourceforge.net/) which has the [surf](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.surf) function (mayavi is a fully-blown 3D visualisation library using hardware acceleration)

Comment: Finally I have decided to use pcolormesh() (it seems to be much faster than pcolor for large array, I do not know why). Also, the `shading=gouraud` option works pretty well.

Comment: @AlexNoir Glad you solved your problem. Please add you solution to the answers, so that other users may profit!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution that suits me is to use the routine `pcolormesh()`. This combined with the option `shading='gouraud'` interpolates the data and smooth the edges. In addition, it works pretty well with large arrays in comparision with pcolor.